# Issues with C++ namespace across file and using directive

Tags: c++, using-directives, using-declaration

Here are a demo code from C++ primer plus about using `using-directive` and `using-declaration` across header files and cpp files, I've made some modification to remove the using declarations in `other` function to have `cout` and `end` and the code errored:

- namesp.h

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace pers
{
    struct Person
    {
        std::string fname;
        std::string lname;
    };
    void getPerson(Person &);
    void showPerson(const Person &);
};

namespace debts
{
    using namespace pers;

    struct Debt
    {
        Person name;
        double amount;
    };
    void getDebt(Debt &);
    void showDebt(const Debt &);
    double sumDebts(const Debt[], int);
}
```

- namesp.cpp

```cpp
#include "namesp.h"

namespace pers
{
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    void getPerson(Person &p)
    {
        cout << "Enter first name: ";
        cin >> p.fname;
        cout << "Enter last name: ";
        cin >> p.lname;
    }

    void showPerson(const Person &p)
    {
        cout << p.lname << ", " << p.fname;
    }
};

namespace debts
{
    void getDebt(Debt &b)
    {
        getPerson(b.name);
        cout << "Enter debt: ";
        cin >> b.amount;
    }

    void showDebt(const Debt &b)
    {
        showPerson(b.name);
        cout << ": $" << b.amount << endl;
    }

    double sumDebts(const Debt bs[], int n)
    {
        double sum;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            sum += bs[i].amount;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

- namessp.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "namesp.h"

void other(void);

int main(void)
{
    other();
    return 0;
}

void other(void)
{
    using namespace debts;
    // using namespace pers;
    // using std::cout;
    // using std::endl;
    Person dg = {"Doodles", "Glister"};
    showPerson(dg);
    cout << endl;    // ERROR: cout and endl was complained no declaration in the scope
    Debt zippy[3] = {{{"Alice", "Jane"}, 100.10}, {{"Bob", "Marley"}, 90.10}, {{"Sam", "Peters"}, 80.10}};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        showDebt(zippy[i]);
    }
    cout << "Total debt: $" << sumDebts(zippy, 3) << endl;
    return;
}
```

- error:

```
$ g++ namesp.cpp namessp.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      1 ↵
namessp.cpp: In function ‘void other()’:
namessp.cpp:20:5: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
     cout << endl;
     ^~~~
namessp.cpp:20:5: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from namessp.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/iostream:61:18: note:   ‘std::cout’
   extern ostream cout;  /// Linked to standard output
                  ^~~~
namessp.cpp:20:13: error: ‘endl’ was not declared in this scope
     cout << endl;
             ^~~~
namessp.cpp:20:13: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39:0,
                 from namessp.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/ostream:590:5: note:   ‘std::endl’
     endl(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os)
     ^~~~
```

Based on my understading, function `another` uses a using directive `using namespace debts`, since using directive is transitive, it implicitly calls `using namespace pers`. But why `cout` and `endl`(viable through using declarations in namespace `pers`) are not visible in function `another`?

Comment: Please add comments on the lines in the shown code where you get the errors.

Comment: As a probable hint about your problem, you need to learn about the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). The compiler will deal *only* with translation units (basically a single source file with all included header files). As such when the compiler is working on `namessp.cpp` it will not know anything that happened in the `namesp.cpp` source file. That include the `using` statements in the `pers` namespace.

Comment: On another and unrelated note, please try to give your source file names that are semantically relevant. It's very hard to distinguish between `namesp.cpp` and  `namessp.cpp` when seeing only the names.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint, I've added a comment to the line that caused the error.

Comment: Thanks for the hint of `translation unit`, if I'm understanding this right, the problem occurs in the preprocessing stage of `namessp.cpp`(one `translation unit`), which basically replaces the `namesp.h` with its content. But in `namesp.h`, namespace `pers` doesn't have those using declarations that nominate `cout` and `endl`(those using declarations are in the `pers` namespace extension in `namesp.cpp`(another `translation unit`)), so those variables are not visible in function `other` as a result.